# Risk connecting PowerShell scripts to a SharePoint instance?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a few team collection sites that are needing some special "move to" functions for specific files between document libraries and other sites.

I have recently inherited the amind right to our SharePoint instance and this is one of the first orders I was given. From what I can tell, in order to accomplish this, I can set up scripts to make this function available to users.

However, I also see that certain functions are changed or turned off when doing this. Is there any other risk that comes with allowing PowerShell scripts to run on a PowerShell site/instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real risk is that it is a lot easier for users to shoot themselves in the foot.

PowerShell scripts are still limited to being able to perform actions that the user running them has permissions to do.  So, for example, if a user does not have permissions to edit items in ListA, then they still won't be able to execute a script to update items in ListA.

However, one of the main strengths of scripting is to be able to perform actions in bulk that would be tedious or time-consuming if performed manually through the UI.  So, if a given user has privileges to delete items in ListA through the UI, and then starts playing around with PowerShell scripts they don't understand, they could very quickly accidentally delete all the items from ListA.

I guess it really boils down to how knowledgeable your users are and how much you trust them with the data they already have access to.